# Http request header map is empty

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I´m trying to send a http request to an api and the api do need a specific header to work.

Until now i tried some diffrent way to send the header. At first i tried to set the header in a httpOptions object and pass them to my `httpClient.get()` function but that didn´t work.

Because im pretty new to angular and typescript I read some articles about how to send http requests. Interceptors should be the right way to go for me here and i modified my code.

Here is my function to make the request:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

public getVersions() {
    let url = baseUrl + '/docs/versions';

    this.http
        .get(url)
        .subscribe(data =>{
            console.log(data);
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    return true;
}
```

Note: `return true;` is here just for testing

Here is my Interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHeaders, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse }
    from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        console.log('intercept http request');
        const duplicate = req.clone({
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('dummy-header', 'dummy-header-info')
        });

        console.log(duplicate.headers.get('dummy-header');
        console.log('new header request');

        return next.handle(duplicate);
    }
}
```

Here are my console logs

```
intercept http request
http-interceptor.ts:19 dummy-header-info
http-interceptor.ts:20 new header request
zone.js:2969 OPTIONS http://192.168.111.106:8089/docs/versions 0 ()
api.service.ts:21 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
error : ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers : HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message : "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name : "HttpErrorResponse"
ok : false
status : 0
statusText : "Unknown Error"
url : null
__proto__ : HttpResponseBase
```

Because of an missing request header the request fails.
So for me it looks like the headers map is an empty map. But why, where is my mistake?

Comment: if you call a different domain for CORS you have to specify the custom header that you want access. Maybe it's back-end modification to do that add in header of option response the custom header allowed

Comment: backend works perfect with postman and other frontend systems

Comment: Why dont you add your headers the normal way? `this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers}) ?`

Comment: As i mentioned in my question i did it before i switched to the Interceptor and it didn´t worked

Comment: And what did not work? For me it works the normal way, could you try again?. Also check possible exceptions on your backend side and post there.

Comment: I get exactly the same result as with the Interceptor so nothing changed on the request

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to know. The response can't have any headers if the request didn't work in the first place.

Comment: @abetteroliver the question is why the request header is not provided and because of the missing request header it fails if i call another function that do not need the header info everything works fine

Comment: You get the error because the header is sent not because it's missing. _"backend works perfect with postman and other frontend systems"_ Because they are not subject to CORS.

Comment: @BraveButter any updates? I faced the same issue

Answer (score 0):

headers: new HttpHeaders().append('dummy-header', 'dummy-header-info')

or const duplicate = req.clone({ setHeaders: { dummy-header: 'dummy-heafer-info' } });

Comment: If you look at my console.log output the header is set but not in the request. But i still tried it and the result is the same as before.

Comment: from your console.log i can only see not in the reponse. can you inspect the request header

Comment: console.log(duplicate.headers.get('dummy-header'); => dummy-header-info

Answer (score -1):

Try to

```
const duplicate = req.clone({
setHeaders: {
        dummy-header: `dummy-heafer-info`
      }
});
```

Comment: Does responses sent and received without Interceptor? Remove interceptor from providers and tell me

Comment: Yes, exactly the same result

Comment: If so. Then Alessandros answer I am standing for, but as you confirmed there is no Cross-Origin issue in the console... Assuming that HttpModule been imported properly

Comment: in this case you don't receive error but only the header will be hidden. The backend/front-end have to had "Access-Control-Allow-Headers:" in options's header handshake

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @Tim I know about that... But its was not possible to apply on a phone...